# Send custom header with Angular 5

Tags: javascript, typescript, http, http-headers, angular5

I am trying to send a custom HTTP Header from the front end app for it to interact with the gateway. This is my angular function:

```
import {Http, Headers, Response, RequestOptions } from ‘@angular/http’;
getXById(id :number){
    let options = nee RequestOptions({ headers : new Headers({“X-fastgate-resource” :”resource_name}) });
    return this.http.get( http://url + “/resource”, options)
```

I expected to see a Header with, “X-fastgate-resource”  as a key, and “resource_name” as value.
What I got was this:

```
Request Headers:
   OPTIONS http://url HTTP/1.1
   host...
   Access-Control-Request-Headers: x-fastgate-resource
```

Comment: The OPTIONS request is the pre-flight request required by CORS. It should be followed up by a GET request if an appropriate status was returned.

Comment: Yes, check your console if your request is blocked because of CORS

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try out something like below.

```
let headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.append('X-fastgate-resource', 'Example');
let options = { headers: headers };
let apiUrl: string = 'http://url';

this.http.get(apiUrl, options);
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

**Try This code:**

```
import {HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
};

**With params**

const url = 'yourapi';
return this.http.post(url, {
    key: value,
    key1: value1
},httpOptions);

**Without Params**

const url = 'yourapi';
return this.http.post(url,httpOptions);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Angular Context.

[Angular Context](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpContext)

This is the simplest way I know of passing data, usually to an interceptor

1. Define a Context Token - usually in the interceptor

   ```
   export const MY_FILENAME = new HttpContextToken<string>(() => "");
   ```
2. Pass the data

   ```
   const context = new HttpContext().set(MY_FILENAME, `${name}.pdf`)
   return this.httpClient.post(url, pdf, {context: context})
   ```
3. Collect the data. Usually in the interceptor

   ```
   const fileName = request.context.get(MY_FILENAME)
   ```